# How to make MUI Snackbar Alert work in mobile view?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Does MUI snackbar alert work in mobile view? Even the example from the [original site](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-snackbar/), along with it's code in [sandbox](https://dtf6z6.csb.app/), don't seem to show a toast in mobile view!

What are my options?
[image]

Comment: The MUI Snackbar "Open Success Snackbar" example works for me in mobile. You could try debugging with Firefox's [about:debugging](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/about_colon_debugging/index.html).